# angular http.get send requst failed error

Tags: angular, token

I send get request url with token but it throw below error

```
Response {_body: "{"auth":false,"message":"No token provided."}", status: 403, ok: false, statusText: "Forbidden", headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}
ok: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/url"
_body: "{"auth":false,"message":"No token provided."}"
```

my service

```
getBusinesses(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return this
    .http
    .get(`${this.uri}`, token).subscribe(res => console.log('Done'));
  }
```

my backend service

```
router.get('/', VerifyToken, function (req, res) {
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.secret);
    User.findById(decoded.id, { password: 0 }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the user.");
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("No user found.");
        Report.find({
            username: user.username,
        })
            .then(report => {
            // res.send(report);
        result = report.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a.username] = r[a.username] || [];
            r[a.username].push(a);
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
        res.send(result);
        // console.log(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Report."
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I know the way of send is wrong

can you please any one explain how to send requst and get response

from server

Comment: You can't inject token this way, have a look from [here](https://www.illucit.com/angular/en-angular-5-httpinterceptor-add-bearer-token-to-httpclient-requests/)

Comment: I use this method: `let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); returh this.http.get(url, options)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending the token by the body, you have to send it by headers

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers